# What will happened without shutting down the Apache HttpClient connectionManager?

Tags: java, apache, http

This problem came out by receiving [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87gDu.png) after sending a http request using apache HttpClients Connection Manager like below. The return result happens very few times.

```
private static final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).setDefaultRequestConfig(configForRequest).build();
httpClient.execute...
```

What happens to the socket in this situation, is it necessary to shutdown the Connect Manager every time after receiving the request? Or is there a proper time to check and shutting it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application. However, if the application makes use of HttpClient only very infrequently, and keeping an idle instance of HttpClient in memory is not warranted, it is highly recommended to explicitly shut down the multithreaded connection manager prior to disposing the HttpClient instance. This will ensure proper closure of all HTTP connections in the connection pool.

So if your application follow this standard, then You only need to intialize HttpClient and ConnectionManager while bootstrapping your application and shut it down while stopping it.

Creating such resources everytime you call a method will not only reduce the efficiency of your application but also error prone to memory leaks.